# Drop control in sub panel and Add new Div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

> **Note**: I have tried other question asked in stackoverflow related to
>   Drag and drop but i'm unable to do so.

First drag and drop a `'Div'` into `'DropDiv'`. Then try to drop textbox in `'Div Sub Panel'`.

**I want to**

1. drop Textbox in `'Div Sub Panel'`.
2. I click To `'Add New Div '` Then Function Not Work

Here is my [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/c85pe50s/) Code

Comment: is there any event which fires when you done with dropping div?

Comment: Into `$(".clspaneldrop").droppable({}); ` block, **drop:** event will be fire on dropping div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only Update `Draggable` in `connectTosortable` in add one more add
>   Class `claspaneldiv`

Add **claspaneldiv**  to **connectTosortable**

```
$(".clsDragItem").draggable({
            connectToSortable: '#MainDroppableDiv,.claspaneldiv',
```

here is demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/yb3dj5om/1/

Answer (score 1):

I thought that `gready:true` would do the trick, which as documentation states:

> by setting this option to true, any parent droppables will not receive the element

but it does not seem to work ( I think because of `sortable`). The code below seems to work but it's surely a hack. Adding this at the end of `MainDroppableDiv`'s `drop` function.

```
$('.claspaneldiv').droppable({
  greedy:true ,
  drop: function(event, ui) {
      console.log('dropped inside!');
      $(this).html('<div>Textbox dropped inside, do your thing...</div>');
      //You may now append ui.draggable element or something
      $('.MainDroppableDiv .clsDragItem.ui-draggable').remove();
  }
});
```

[Full demo here!](http://jsfiddle.net/8odoros/s1krzw7u/1/)

Comment: Thanks fast response. but i want to placeholder in  `Div Sub Panel` and after drop covert to HTML

Comment: `Add New Div` actually works. You just have to select `Load type: No wrap in body`, that's in jsFiddle's javascript settings.

Comment: i fetch error `VM2323:1Uncaught ReferenceError: AddnewDiv 'is not defined` . if you possible to try to my jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks... jsFiddle's javascript settings.done.